# How to reach the power plant?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I'm trying to do the SideOp #6 (Secure Stun Arm). It is at the power plant. However, I can't find a way to reach the plant.

I picked the closest drop (south of the plant) point but it is a huge rocky place. I tried to walk around it, but no success.

It is quite annoying at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This video tutorial shows a map and then how to get there with D-Horse:

A screenshot of the video showing the map with highlighted path:

[image: Getting to the power plant]

Comment: I know but I don't see how to explain it better than in the video.  "Just after the third little rock, slightly turn on the right and then run until the next bush; there you should be able to seen a couple of ferns ..."  Meh.

Comment: Still better than having only the link.

Comment: 1/ There's more than only a link; "link only" answers only contain a link and are usually a way to point out how dumb a question can be, "let me google that for you" way -- not the case here 2/ No, in this case you won't make me believe than a long text would be more efficient than a few seconds of video.  But I know too well how endless and stupid these conversations can get, so I'll add a picture so you can chill out.

Comment: At the point in time that comment was made, this was just a link to a YouTube video. Since we are not YouTube we have no control over their retention of videos your "answer" being an "answer" was entirely dependant on some third party not deleting the video. Now that you've added an image that is no longer the case, since now your answer contains the answer.

Comment: Point taken.  But also it basically means that any media hosted anywhere else than on arqade itself is considered irrelevant because you cannot guarantee its sustainability on arqade...  Makes sense somehow, but sounds a bit over the top, especially since there's no way to host video (at least not that I know about).  Lastly I wasn't aware of this new policy here, sorry.

Comment: The policy isn't new; images are okay as answers, videos, by themselves, are not. It's been that way for a rather long time.